# Function nested in each() that is being applied to all elements instead of individual

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery script that I'm using to apply pagination to a series of classes. Mostly everything is working properly except that I have have a nested function (showPage) that should only be applied to the current class but is using elements across all the classes and applying the actions to the last item.

Have already tried switching to a for loop rather than an each loop but that provided similar functionality but had the same issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var lists = document.getElementsByClassName('content_display');
  listSize = 5;
  var fourWide = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 800px)");
  var threeWide = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)")
  if (fourWide.matches) {
    // Screen is less than 800px
    listSize = 4;
  }
  if (fourWide.matches) {
    // Screen is less than 600px
    listSize = 3;
  }

  $(lists).each(function() {
    var contentCount = $(this).find('ul li').length
    var pageCount = contentCount / listSize;
    if (contentCount < listSize)
      $(this).find(".content_more").hide()
    var $e = $(this)
    var $f = $(this).find('.content_item')
    for (var i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {

      $(this).find(".pagination").append('<a href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a> ');
    }
    $(this).find(".pagination a").first().addClass("active")
    showPage = function(page) {
      $f.hide();
      $f.each(function(n) {
        if (n >= listSize * (page - 1) && n < listSize * page)
          $(this).show();
      });
    }

    showPage(1);

    $(this).find(".pagination a").click(function() {
      $e.find(".pagination a").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      showPage(parseInt($(this).text()))
    });
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content_row">
  <div class="content_display">
    <div class="contentList_container">
      <ul>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content_more"></div>
    <div class="pagination"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content_row">
  <div class="content_display">
    <div class="contentList_container">
      <ul>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content_more"></div>
    <div class="pagination"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content_row">
  <div class="content_display">
    <div class="contentList_container">
      <ul>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content_more"></div>
    <div class="pagination"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear! Why and where are you trying to add or remove the class? Can you edit the question only to have associated code?

Comment: Check the `showPage` variable, it's acting as a global reference, being overwritten in successive loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `showpage` as a local variable. Since there's no variable declaration, you're overwriting the global variable each time through the loop, so all the anchors are calling the `showpage` function for the last DIV.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var lists = document.getElementsByClassName('content_display');
  var listSize = 5;
  var fourWide = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 800px)");
  var threeWide = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)")
  if (fourWide.matches) {
    // Screen is less than 800px
    listSize = 4;
  }
  if (fourWide.matches) {
    // Screen is less than 600px
    listSize = 3;
  }

  $(lists).each(function() {
    var contentCount = $(this).find('ul li').length
    var pageCount = contentCount / listSize;
    if (contentCount < listSize)
      $(this).find(".content_more").hide()
    var $e = $(this)
    var $f = $(this).find('.content_item')
    for (var i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {

      $(this).find(".pagination").append('<a href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a> ');
    }
    $(this).find(".pagination a").first().addClass("active")
    var showPage = function(page) {
      $f.hide();
      $f.each(function(n) {
        if (n >= listSize * (page - 1) && n < listSize * page)
          $(this).show();
      });
    }

    showPage(1);

    $(this).find(".pagination a").click(function() {
      $e.find(".pagination a").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      showPage(parseInt($(this).text()))
    });
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content_row">
  <div class="content_display">
    <div class="contentList_container">
      <ul>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content_more"></div>
    <div class="pagination"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content_row">
  <div class="content_display">
    <div class="contentList_container">
      <ul>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content_more"></div>
    <div class="pagination"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content_row">
  <div class="content_display">
    <div class="contentList_container">
      <ul>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
        <li class="content_item"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content_more"></div>
    <div class="pagination"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```